# How to change Julia logs path?

Tags: path, julia, logfile

How can I change path to log files in Julia?

I have changed `$JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` (which is `~/.julia` by default) to a custom location, and the external packages are indeed installed into that location. However, log files (history, in particular) are still written to `~/.julia/logs/repl_history.jl`, which creates problems if Julia is installed in an NFS directory used by multiple machines:

```
ERROR: Invalid history file (~/.julia/logs/repl_history.jl) format:
If you have a history file left over from an older version of Julia,
try renaming or deleting it.
Invalid character: '\0' at line 31
```

How can one force Julia to use `$JULIA_DEPOT_PATH/logs` for log files instead of the default `~/.julia/logs`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_HISTORY-1?

Comment: Exactly what I needed :-) Thank you!